# how to save ui htmlcontent input fields in product save/edit form

Tags: magento2

i have added some fields in my product form using htmlcontent like below:

```xml
    <htmlContent name="properties" sortOrder="20">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="wrapper" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Properties</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <wrapper>
                <canShow>true</canShow>
                <componentType>fieldset</componentType>
            </wrapper>
        </settings>
        <block name="properties" class="Offer\CedProductFastEntry\Block\Helper\Form\Properties" template="Offer_CedProductFastEntry::product/properties.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="parentComponent" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form.block_properties</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
            <block as="content" class="Offer\CedProductFastEntry\Block\Product\Edit\FastEntry" name="fast-entry" template="Offer_CedProductFastEntry::product/edit/slideout/fastentry_form.phtml" />
        </block>
    </htmlContent>
```

in the htmlContent i create some input fields and i want to save them.

however they are not exists in form post request and i cant recieve them in server side! how can is bind them to product form? (i dont want to use ui field and fieldset, so don't change the htmlContent to field and fieldset)

Comment: Hello, you should check on chrome developer tools the values of the POST (Save action of the product) and check if the input values are there and the names are there, once you have checked that there's the informations that you want on the POST then you'll have to take a look on vendor/magento-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save and maybe rewrite it adding your fields, or even better using an observer and getting the fields. First of all on the POST call there's the fields?

Comment: i have said that POST fields are not there. the problem is not existing my custom fields in POST request.